# Does Proverbs 5:22a mean that one particular person's inquities would also cause others involved to be punished/disciplined?

Tags: translation-philosophy, sin, proverbs, judgement

> Proverbs 5:21-23
>
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 21 For the ways of a man are before the eyes of the Lord, And He
> watches all his paths.
> **22 His own iniquities will capture the wicked,** And he will be held with the cords of his sin. 23 He will die for lack of instruction, And
> in the greatness of his folly he will go astray.
>
> Proverbs 5:21-23
>
> New King James Version
>
> 21 For the ways of man are before the eyes of the Lord, And He
> [a]ponders all his paths.
> **22 His own iniquities entrap the wicked man,** And he is caught in the cords of his sin. 23 He shall die for lack of instruction, And in
> the greatness of his folly he shall go astray.
>
> Proverbs 5:21-23
>
> English Standard Version
>
> 21 For a man's ways are before the eyes of the Lord,
> and he ponders[a] all his paths.
> **22 The iniquities of the wicked ensnare him,**
> and he is held fast in the cords of his sin. 23 He dies for lack of discipline,
> and because of his great folly he is led astray.
>
> 5:21-23 The Westminster Leningrad Codex
>
> 21 כִּ֤י נֹ֨כַח׀ עֵינֵ֣י יְ֭הוָה דַּרְכֵי־אִ֑ישׁ וְֽכָל־מַעְגְּלֹתָ֥יו
> מְפַלֵּֽס׃
>
> 22 עַֽווֹנוֹתָ֗יו יִלְכְּדֻנ֥וֹ אֶת־הָרָשָׁ֑ע וּבְחַבְלֵ֥י חַ֝טָּאת֗וֹ
> יִתָּמֵֽךְ׃
>
> 23 ה֗וּא יָ֭מוּת בְּאֵ֣ין מוּסָ֑ר וּבְרֹ֖ב אִוַּלְתּ֣וֹ יִשְׁגֶּֽה׃ פ

The NASB1995 and NKJV translation of Proverbs 5:22a seems to suggest that a particular person's iniquity will discipline/punish "the wicked" in general.
To elaborate by example,  let's say a CEO of a major firm is involved in financial fraud, and some of his subordinates like his CFO, CTO, etc, are also involved under the auspices of the CEO.

( Side Note:  As I quickly reviewed the various commentaries on biblehub, I did Not find anything that reflected the aforementioned view but I could be wrong: https://biblehub.com/commentaries/proverbs/5-22.htm   )

Therefore, would Proverbs 5:22a be relevant to the aforementioned example?  Could it mean that the CEO's sin in committing financial fraud would lead to his CFO, CTO, etc, being punished/disciplined due to their involvement as subordinates to the CEO?

Related question postings:

[How does sin trap someone and hold them captive (Proverbs 5:22-23)?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35732/how-does-sin-trap-someone-and-hold-them-captive-proverbs-522-23)

Answer (score 2):

#### Does Proverbs 5:22a mean that one particular person's inquities would also cause others involved to be punished/disciplined?

One way to look at this is from the linguistic side.

The Hebrew word for "wicked" in this verse is הָרָשָׁ֑ע *hā·rā·šā‘* which is in the singular. We can compare this to Psalm 37:14 where the "wicked" in this verse is plural, רְשָׁעִים֮ *rə·šā·‘îm* (both words come from the root רָשְׁע *rasha* [[Strong's H7563](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/7563.htm)]).

Further clues are the surrounding text:

- "**he will be held** with the cords of his sin."
- "**He will die** for lack of instruction"
- "in the greatness of his folly **he will go astray**"

Each one of these phrases is in the singular in the Hebrew text. So going to your example of the CEO, **he** will be judged for **his** actions. The CFO, CTO, etc. will also be judged for **their** actions if they knew what the CEO was doing and were willing participants in the CEO's actions.

Answer (score 1):

The best versions suggest a simple idea - sin contains the seeds of its own (ultimate) destruction.  Note the following translations of Prov 5:22 -

- NIV: The evil deeds of the wicked ensnare them; the cords of their sins hold them fast.
- ESV: The iniquities of the wicked ensnare him, and he is held fast in the cords of his sin.
- BSB: The iniquities of a wicked man entrap him; the cords of his sin entangle him.
- NKJV: His own iniquities entrap the wicked man, And he is caught in the cords of his sin.

Now, it is a matter of common experience that sin often produces diverse consequences that adversely affects many more than the sinner; however, the focus of Prov 5:22 is about the denigrating, demoralizing and degrading affects of sin on the sinner - an evil done is easier next time until the sinful habit is difficult to break.  This idea is taught many times in the Bible - see appendix below.

Note the comments of Ellicott -

> (22, 23) His own iniquities . . .—The final scene in the life of the
> profligate is here described. He has sinned so long that he is “tied
> and bound,” hand and foot, with the “chain of his sins,” and cannot
> get free even had he the wish to do so.

MacLaran  is similar:

> We all know that anything once done becomes easier to do again. That
> is true about both good and bad actions, but ‘ill weeds grow apace,’
> and it is infinitely easier to form a bad habit than a good one. The
> young shoot is green and flexible at first, but it soon becomes woody
> and grows high and strikes deep. We can all verify the statement of
> our text by recalling the tremors of conscience, the self-disgust, the
> dread of discovery which accompanied the first commission of some evil
> deed, and the silence of undisturbed, almost unconscious facility,
> that accompanied later repetitions of it. Sins of sense and animal
> passion afford the most conspicuous instances of this, but it is by no
> means confined to these. We have but to look steadily at our own lives
> to be aware of the working of this solemn law in them, however clear
> we may be of the grosser forms of evil deeds. For us all it is true
> that custom presses on us ‘with a weight, heavy as frost and deep
> almost as life,’ and that it is as hard for the Ethiopian to change
> his skin or the leopard his spots as for those who ‘are accustomed to
> do evil’ to ‘do good.’

**APPENDIX - Sin ultimately recoils on the sinner**

This same idea is expressed another way in some places where God allows sin and evil to reap its own consequences and cause its own downfall.

- Job 5:13 - He catches the wise in their own craftiness, and the schemes of the wily are brought to a quick end.
- Ps 5:10 - Declare them guilty, O God; let them fall by their own devices. Drive them out for their many transgressions, for they have rebelled against You.
- Ps 7:15 - He has dug a hole and hollowed it out; he has fallen into a pit of his own making.
- Ps 9:16 - The LORD is known by the justice He brings; the wicked are ensnared by the work of their hands.
- Ps 69:22 - Let their own table before them become a snare; and when they are at peace, let it become a trap.
- Ps 141:10 - Let the wicked fall into their own nets, while I pass by in safety.
- Prov 5:22 - The iniquities of a wicked man entrap him; the cords of his sin entangle him.
- Prov 11:6 - The righteousness of the upright delivers them, but the faithless are trapped by their own desires.
- Prov 12:13 - An evil man is trapped by his rebellious speech, but a righteous man escapes from trouble.
- Prov 28:10 - He who leads the upright along the path of evil will fall into his own pit, but the blameless will inherit what is good.
- Hos 11:6 - Job 5:13 - He catches the wise in their own craftiness, and the schemes of the wily are brought to a quick end.